# Multiple upload but upload files separately to not overload PHP

Tags: php, upload

I'm currently working on a photoalbum thing on my website and was wondering is there is a way to upload files separately even though I selected multiple files for upload, let me explain:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name='uploads[]' type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php
$y=count($_FILES['uploads']);
for($x=0;$x<$y;$x++) {
    echo $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$x];
    echo "<br>";  
}
?>
```

So I've got these simple lines of code. And basically (As you can see) you can upload multiple files. But let's say that that my 'upload_max_filesize' is at 8M. I can only select 4 images of 2MB each to upload successfully, otherwise I overwrite the max upload size. My question is, is there a PHP way to keep the form structure the same but let the script handle one file at the time so I can upload 5.000 files from 5MB's each for example?

Comment: no. php cannot do anything about how the client uploads files. if the user selects to upload 500 files of 500gigs total, PHP will barf, but you can't do anything about that, because the barfing occurs **BEFORE** your code will ever execute. Your code will not execute until AFTER the upload has completed (succesfully or not).

Comment: You could upload them one-by-one using AJAX …

Comment: @MarcB I realised that but thought there maybe was a creative way with array's before uploading, but thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @CBroe Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: you could set the `max_file_uploads=1` in the php.ini file and then provide an error message when the user tries more than 1, as@CBroe says you can handle asynchronous uploading with ajax see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831883/upload-file-with-jquery/6832372#6832372